# Subclassing numpy.ndarray - why is __array_finalize__ not being called twice here?

Tags: python, numpy, inheritance

According to [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html) primer on subclassing `ndarray`, the `__array_finalize__` method is guaranteed to be called, no matter if the subclass is instantiated directly, casted as a view or created from a template.

In particular, when calling the constructor explicitly, the order of methods called is `__new__` -> `__array_finalize__` -> `__init__`.

I have the following simple subclass of `ndarray` which allows an additional `title` attribute.

```
class Frame(np.ndarray):    
    def __new__(cls, input_array, title='unnamed'):
        print 'calling Frame.__new__ with title {}'.format(title)
        self = input_array.view(Frame) # does not call __new__ or __init__
        print 'creation of self done, setting self.title...'
        self.title = title
        return self

    def __array_finalize__(self, viewed):
        # if viewed is None, the Frame instance is being created by an explicit
        # call to the constructor, hence Frame.__new__ has been called and the
        # title attribute is already set
        #
        # if viewed is not None, the frame is either being created by view
        # casting or from template, in which case the title of the viewed object
        # needs to be forwarded to the new instance
        print '''calling Frame.__array_finalize__ with type(self) == {} and
        type(viewed) == {}'''.format(type(self), type(viewed))

        if viewed is not None:
            self.title = getattr(viewed, 'title', 'unnamed')

        print self.title
```

which produces the following output:

```
>>> f = Frame(np.arange(3), 'hallo')
calling Frame.__new__ with title hallo
calling Frame.__array_finalize__ with type(self) == <class '__main__.Frame'> and
        type(viewed) == <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
unnamed
creation of self done, setting self.title...
>>> f.title
'hallo'
```

As you can see, `__array_finalize__` is being called as a result of the line

```
 self = input_array.view(Frame)
```

Question: why is `__array_finalize__` not being called again as part of the `__new__` -> `__array_finalize__` -> `__init__` chain?

Comment: I would assume it is because `__array_finalize__` is only called once per object.  numpy knows your `self` has already had `__array_finalize__` called so it doesn't call it again.  Not sure exactly which example you're referring to, but when I put some `print` calls into the RealisticInfoArray example on that page, `__array_finalize__` is only called once.  I also don't see where on that page it suggests the new -> finalize -> init order you mention, or why you think it would call the finalizer twice.

Comment: @BrenBarn I  got the idea that the methods are called in that order from the output in [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#the-role-of-array-finalize) section where the example has all three methods and because the text mentions "`ndarray.__new__` passes `__array_finalize__` the new object". So I'm curious why my `__new__` method does not seem to do this.  My example itself is from [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#slightly-more-realistic-example-attribute-added-to-existing-array) section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the documentation you link to, it describes how `ndarray.__new__` will call `__array_finalize__` on the arrays it constructs. And your class's `__new__` method is causing that to happen when you create your instance as a `view` of an existing array. The `view` method on the array argument is calling `ndarray.__new__` for you, and it calls your `__array_finalize__` method before the instance is returned to you.

You don't see `__array_finalize__` called twice because you're not calling `ndarray.__new__` a second time. If your `__new__` method included a call to `super().__new__` in addition to the `view` call, you probably would see `__array_finalized__` called twice. Such behavior would probably be buggy (or at least, slower than necessary), so it's no surprise you're not doing it!

Python doesn't automatically call overridden methods when the overriding subclass's method gets called. It's up to the overriding method to call (or not call) the overridden version (directly with `super` or, as in this case, indirectly via another object's `view` method).

Comment: I somehow did not corrctly process that the `ndarray`'s `__new__` method was the culprit for the `__array_finalize__` and that it did not happen due to some magic. Thanks.